# Display different Text value depending on formula field return values

Tags: formula-field

I have a formula field to display hours of meetings called (Meeting_Durations_Hours__c). Since there are meetings with many durations I want to segment the durations Ex: 0-2 hour, 2.1-4 hour likewise. Whole purpose of this is to group the meetings by these segments in the my standard report for meetings. I tried bucket field in stndrd reports but it wont automatically do this as we have to add values manually to each created bucket field.

So I created a Text formula field for hour segments called (Meeting_Durations_Hours_Segment__c)

Meeting_Durations_Hours__c is also a Text Formula Field.

and I want to do something like this :-

```
IF((Meeting_Durations_Hours__c ),
<0,"Less than a hour",
0>3, "0-3 Hours",
3>5, "3.1-5 Hours",
5>10, "5.1-10 Hours",
"None")
```

But it's displaying an error:-

> Error: Incorrect parameter type for operator '<'. Expected Text,
>   received Number

How can I do this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use the `VALUE(text)` function as below.

```
IF(VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c )<1,"Less than a hour", "Greater than Hour"))))))
```

> Update

For your condition, you can use nested IF statements.

```
IF(VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c  )<1,"Less than a hour",
    IF(AND(VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c )>=1,VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c  )< 3),"0-3 Hours",
        IF(AND(VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c )>=3,VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c  )< 5),"3-5 Hours",
            IF(AND(VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c )>=5,VALUE(Meeting_Durations_Hours__c  )<= 10),"5-10 Hours",
            "None")
        )
    )
)
```

*note - This formula is not tested, you may have to fix the syntax error if there is any*

Comment: This answer works. But I tried for many cases as below:-                 IF(VALUE( Meeting_Durations_Hours__c )
<1,"Less than a hour", 
1>3, "Less than 3 hours",
3>5, "Less than 5 hours",
"None")        -----but it shows an error "Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 7" @Saroj Bera

Comment: Check my updated answer. If this answer has solved your question you can use the check mark next to it to mark it as such.

Comment: You answer worked without any errors ! Great! (Y)